# Multiple file reading with FileReader and readAsArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, file-upload, callback

I'm trying to read and add multiple files to an array. I've already found out that readAsArrayBuffer is a asynchronous function, so i need to wait for previous uploads to end. I tried to use callbacks but i failed.

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="file-input" type="file" multiple="" accept="image/*">
</form>
<div id="upload-list"></div>
```

Here's js file:

```js
var fileList = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  function addFiles(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = (function(file) {
        return function() {
          fileList.push(reader.result);
          $('#upload-list').append('<div class="upload-list-item">' + file.name '</div>');
        }
      })(file);
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      console.log(fileList);
    }
  }
  $('#file-input').on('change', function(e) {
    addFiles(e.target.files);
  });
}
```

So now i have new FileReader each iteration, i got rid from `Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs` error, now i have the same files in my array, although I selected different.

[image: google chrome dev]

Comment: `fileList.push(reader.result);` ... the problem is what `reader` will be (you fixed `file` using an IIFE, but not `reader`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that `reader` is going to be clobbered - using .forEach will mean each iteration is safe in its own closure - no need for IIFE kludges either

```
function addFiles(files) {
    // files is not a regular Array
    [].forEach.call(files, function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            fileList.push(reader.result);
            $('#upload-list').append('<div class="upload-list-item">' + file.name + '</div>');
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
}
```

However this does not guarantee any particular "order" of the `$('#upload-list').append` - because asynchronous code is asynchronouos

Using Promises (which CAN be polyfilled for older browsers) you could do something like

```
function addFiles(files) {
    return Promise.all([].map.call(files, function (file) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function () {
                resolve({ result: reader.result, file: file });
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
    })).then(function (results) {
        results.forEach(function (result) {
            $('#upload-list').append('<div class="upload-list-item">' + result.file.name + '</div>');
        });
        return results;
    });
}
```

This will guarantee the order that `$('#upload-list').append` is called

Comment: forEach worked for me, thanks! except i placed `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);` into forEach. i think, i understood that things with IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors at `+ file.name`, and missing `)` at `.ready()`, defined parameter and pass `reader` to IIFE

```js
var fileList = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  function addFiles(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = (function(file, reader) {
        return function() {
          fileList.push(reader.result);
          $('#upload-list').append('<div class="upload-list-item">' + file.name + '</div>');
        }
      })(file, reader);
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      console.log(fileList);
    }
  }
  $('#file-input').on('change', function(e) {
    addFiles(e.target.files);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="file-input" type="file" multiple="" accept="image/*">
</form>
<div id="upload-list"></div>
```

Comment: @JaromandaX Do you suggest including code at Answer which passed `reader` to the IIFE?

Comment: Not at all.  forEach will fix this without resorting to new and overused toys like async/await that break older browser compatibility for no benefit at all

Comment: @JaromandaX Would not. Would probably define only a single instance of `FileReader` as well

Comment: @JaromandaX Always wondered what that :p meant. Am out of any and all loops

Comment: it's a "tongue hanging out" smiley (a smiley is a text only emoji - not sure if you needed that explanation :p )

Comment: @guest271314 yeah, sorry, my bad, i deleted some extra things from code to post it here